# Does the size of the data stored in the record affect the Clustered index performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables.

1. Primary fact table (FactTable)
2. A table containing int field + other 'n' varchar(50) fields(Table001)
3. A table containing int field + other 'n' varchar(max) fields(Table002)

Records in each table: #5 million rows

query:

```
select * from FactTable f with (nolock)
inner join Table001 t001 with (nolock) on f.id = t001.id
inner join Table002 t002 with (nolock) on t002.id = f.id
where f.datefield = '2014-02-01'
```

All the tables have a clustered index on the field 'Id'(which is used in joining the tables i.e., like a foreign key)

The clustered indices are not fragmented(fragmentation percentage < 5%) on all tables

The case is when I join all three tables, I am seeing in the Execution plan that the cost of joining with table002 is higher than table001. Is there any reason for this behavior?

Link to XML Execution plan: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7E436AE9D73999B0%21120

I couldn't paste the xml content because of size restriction.

Another link : http://www.expinos.in/ExecutionPlan.sqlplan

Comment: Is your data only read? Otherwise NOLOCK may return wrong results, you know. Better use with (readcommitted).

Comment: Yes It is static for most of the time, there are inserts only during certain hour of the day, So NOLOCK won't hurt data integrity

Comment: Can you post the XML version of the execution plan?

Comment: The execution plan can be found in https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7E436AE9D73999B0%21120

Comment: Is the data in the Varchar(max) field generally larger than 8K bytes ? If so then it will not fit in the page with the id number and would be stored else where in the large object sotrage area for the table. That would require an extra lookup to get to the data than the table with just the varchar(50).

Comment: Yes the size would normally be more than 8kb, are there any ways to reduce the cost of this join?

Comment: Your observations are not bourne out by this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd271/1, this is hardly conclusive but does raise a question.

Answer (score 1):

The size of columns in a row, that are not in an index, will not effect the performance of the containing index itself.

However,

Large non-indexed columns will effect the performance of table based operations. You'll get less rows on a page, so when scanning, you'll have to read more pages.

Large non-indexed columns that are included in a query will have an obvious direct effect on query performance. You'll have to read bigger values from disk/memory, although the optimiser will try to do this late.

The size of the columns in an index effects the performance of the index.

The size of columns in the clustered index will effect the performance of all indecies on the table

---

Is it easier to compare 1 byte or 10000? Is it easier to hash 1 byte or 10000? Is it easier to read 1 byte from disk/memory or 10000?

Comment: That makes sense, but I just ran a quick check on the above mentioned query, without including any field from Table002, but still the execution plan says 60 % for that join alone. Is there any way to reduce the cost of this join?

Comment: @M22an, I can't see your query plan, are both joins satisfied with an index seek?

Comment: The join with Table001 has an index scan and Table002 has an index seek

Comment: I have added another link the execution plan